# Laravel - how to create a dropdown with specific entry selected depending upon database value

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have 2 cases but the simplest is as follows:
A database column is filled with a string representing a time (eg class at 4:30). When a user adds a new entry, the time is selected from a dropdown by the user. On edit, the dropdown data is passed from the controller as well as the database row to be edited ($classtime and by extension $classtime->start_time which contains the original value selected by the user...04:30). The relevant code is:

```
$classtime = Classtime::find($id);    /* get the db row to be edited */
$data = array(
                'clubs' => Club::all(),
                'start_times' => [
                    '09:00','09:30','10:00','10:30','11:00','11:30','12:00','12:30','01:00','01:30','02:00','02:30','03:00','03:30','04:00','04:30','05:00','05:30','06:00','06:30','07:00','07:30','08:00','08:30', 
                ],);
```

Adding a new entry stores (say) 04:30 as a string in the field 'start_time'. When it comes time to edit the entry, I want the dropdown list to show 04:30 as the selected value.
In building the list in the view, I have the following:

```
@foreach($data['start_times'] as $stime)
         <option value="{{ $stime }}">{{ $stime }}</option>
@endforeach
```

I also have $classtime as the database record.

My question is:
How do I compare $stime (array element) to the current value in the database row
($classtime->start_time) and based upon an equal comparison, insert 'selected' into the option?
I would have thought that this was a common issue but I cannot find anything that seems to match this, nor can I derive a solution from the responses I have found.
Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers
Geoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
@foreach($data['start_times'] as $stime)
     <option value="{{ $stime }}" @if(App\Classtime::latest()->first()->start_time === $stime) selected @endif>{{ $stime }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hi, @user1988589 if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: Update: the above solution worked great with string data but failed with integer data. Turned out I had to 'cast' the variables to allow the if match to work as expected.